# Как распознать темные места на камере

Tags: android

Предположим, что юзер в моем приложении включает фронталку или камеру, приложение находит темное место на видео и "закрашивает" его. Т.е, например, юзер наводит камеру на черный, выключенный монитор, а программа вместо экрана монитора подставляет картинку. Подскажите, как или с помощью чего такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Думаю придется разобраться с opencv и интеграцией си кода в андроид

Comment: А как можно картинку наложить на фото?